# I keep getting a Null exception when using g.FillEllipse();

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi

I am a beginner at this so cut me a little slack please. I am trying to draw a dot on the form window at the location where the mouse is clicked. I keep getting a Null Exception at g.FillEllipse is called. What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
namespace ConvexHullScan
{

public partial class convexHullForm : Form
{
    Graphics g;
    //Brush blue = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
    Pen bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 10);
    Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red);

    public convexHullForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    }     

    private void convexHullForm_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {

            int x, y;
            Brush blue = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
            **g.FillEllipse(blue, x, y, 20, 20);**
        }                                             
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace   `Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();` with just   `g = this.CreateGraphics();` because otherwise you are defining a new variable that lives only inside the scope of the `mainForm_Load` function rather than assigning a value to the variable defined at the higher-level scope of `convexHullForm`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your end goal is, but those dots drawn with CreateGraphics() will only be temporary.  They will get erased when the form repaints itself, such as when you minimize and restore, or if another window obscures yours.  To make them "persistent", use the supplied `e.Graphics` in the **Paint() Event** of the Form:

```
public partial class convexHullForm : Form
{

    private List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();

    public convexHullForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(convexHullForm_Paint);
        this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(convexHullForm_MouseDown);
    }

    private void convexHullForm_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Points.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            this.Refresh();
        }                                             
    }

    void convexHullForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Point pt in Points)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, pt.X, pt.Y, 20, 20);
        }
    }

}
```